# Debug eureka-client side http requests

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am trying to register my monolithic application to eureka server (first migration step into microservices world). The client & server versions that I use is 1.5.3. The registration request fails, due to bad request error.

My java code that creates the eureka client is:

```
private EurekaClient createEurekaClient(){
    EurekaInstanceConfig instanceConfig = new MyDataCenterInstanceConfig(MY_NAMESPACE);
    InstanceInfo instanceInfo = new EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider(instanceConfig).get();
    ApplicationInfoManager applicationInfoManager = new ApplicationInfoManager(instanceConfig, instanceInfo);
    return new DiscoveryClient(applicationInfoManager, new DefaultEurekaClientConfig());
    }
```

eureka-client.properties:

```
my-namespace.vipAddress=eureka
my-namespace.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.region=default
my-namespace.name=MY-APP
my-namespace.port=8080
my-namespace.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:9999/eureka/v2/
```

The logs output:

```
2016-09-20 10:35:54,325 DEBUG [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] (AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:60) - Jersey HTTP POST http://localhost:9999/eureka/v2//apps/MY-APP with instance 7010; statusCode=400
2016-09-20 10:35:54,326 DEBUG [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] (ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:282) - Released connection is not reusable.
2016-09-20 10:35:54,326 DEBUG [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] (ConnPoolByRoute.java:429) - Releasing connection [{}->http://localhost:9999][null]
2016-09-20 10:35:54,326 DEBUG [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] (ConnPoolByRoute.java:676) - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2016-09-20 10:35:54,326 DEBUG [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] (RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121) - Pinning to endpoint null
2016-09-20 10:35:54,326 WARN  [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] (RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:127) - Request execution failure with status code 400; retrying on another server if available
```

The server returns a 400 error code which means bad request, so am looking for a way to print the full registration request to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause to this issue, the **com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind** that used in my project was outdated (version 2.1.1). While the eureka client needs minimum 2.5.4 version.